# Creating a construction function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to create a constructor function called course that takes appropriate parameters and sets course_code, course_number, units, fall_only and description as attributes. Also need to add a method to the prototype of course that outputs to the console whether the course is fall_only and another method that returns the concatenation of course_code and course_number. I am new to Javascript and unaware on how to start.

Comment: You could start by googling "javascript class"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). After doing some research and searching for related topics on SO, try it yourself. If you're stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt note exactly where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: may i ask why you need a constructor?

Comment: @PramithChathuranga I don't see how this is related specifically to ES6, the OP has stated nothing about that (not even mentioned `class` syntax). At best, the [reactjs] tag should have been removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
class Course {
  constructor(course_code, course_number, units, fall_only, description) {
    this.course_code = course_code;
    this.course_number = course_number;
    this.units = units;
    this.fall_only = fall_only;
    this.description = description;
  }

  log_fall_only() {
    console.log(this.fall_only);
  }

  concatenation() {
    return String(this.course_code).concat(this.course_number);
  }
}

const course = new Course(404, 101, 'joules', true, 'Intro to Statistics');
course.log_fall_only();
console.log(course.concatenation());
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes to learn about classes in JavaScript. Once you're familiar with classes you can make a Course class with the needed constructor and method.

Comment: this should be a comment.